# Google Charts not displaying IE-9

Tags: javascript, php, charts

I have Google charts on my web page. All values are generated by php script. But on IE-9 charts not come up (empty place). Fine with IE-11.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsapi.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Name1',        'Nane2',            'Name3,                'Name4',          'Name5',             'Name6',             'Name7',        'Name8',             'Name9'],
    ['',  <?php echo $E; ?>,       <?php echo $B; ?>,     <?php echo $H; ?>,      <?php echo $Q; ?>,      <?php echo $M; ?>,      <?php echo $F; ?>  ,   <?php echo $O; ?>,   <?php echo $R; ?>,          <?php echo $OTR; ?> ],

  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Downtime Report',
    vAxis: {title: 'Downtime Minutes', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `src="jsapi.js"` better try with direct google API `src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"`. To be honest I've no idea about the issue. I have not faced any browser issue with google chart. I assume trying google api in local src is the issue..